# Deleting media file on Android 4.4.2 Kitkat

Tags: android, mp3, delete-file

I have provided permission of `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAG`E in Manifest file and trying to delete a media file in my code. But unable to delete it. I am able to delete files in Internal Storage. Please help how to do this. How to delete in Kitkat since I read that Kitkat stops write access to other files.

```
 if(files2.get(i).exists())
                        {
                            Log.d("file exists","true");
                            if(files2.get(i).canWrite())
                            {
                                Log.d("file write","true");
                                fileDeleted=files2.get(i).delete();  // returns false
                                Log.d("file deleted??",""+fileDeleted);
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: You are not showing paths. You are not showing errors. You don't tell which part of your code gets executed. What do you mean with "Kitkat stops write access to other files"?

Comment: Path is :/storage/extSdCard/Music/baby.mp3 and I dont get any error.File just doesnt get deleted.

Comment: Does .canWrite() return true? You are not telling which part of the code gets executed. I asked you before. You should also log if canWrite is false.

Comment: Sorry for that. canWrite returns true .  fileDeleted=files2.get(i).delete(); returns false.

Comment: Mmmm that is strange. But anyhow under KitKat an app can only write/delete files on removable storage if the files are in a specific app directory. That's often /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/appname/files. The Media directory is not yours so it cannot be changed. If you have an M8 then you are lucky as HTC allows.

Comment: But there should be a workaround right :( . Because other Music players are able to delete the media file. for example : Samsung Music player.

Comment: If you have a Samsung then the Samsung Music Player belongs to the so called system apps. Well they can. Or easier: that Music directory belongs to the player.

Comment: So I cant delete in anyway in user defined app ? :(